# Uncontrolled data used in path expression

Tags: java, android, codeql

I am getting a uncontrolled data used in path expression error in codeql for the following code block:

```
public static File getObjAsFile(LibraryObject object, LibraryObjectType objectType, boolean encrypt, File tempFile) { // Step 1
...
try {

    if (encrypt) {
        ...
    } else {
        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {  // Step 2
            byte[] outputBytes = serializedJson.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(outputBytes);
        }
    }
return tempFile;
} catch (Exception e) {
  LOG.e("Unable to create the library object export file {}", e);
}}
```

I am getting "This path depends on user provided value" at steps 1 and 2. Not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: It would probably be more interesting here who is calling `getObjAsFile`, respectively the call path CodeQL reported from the user input (or at least what it considered user input) to the `getObjAsFile` method.